# trying to add a list to a text file, getting errors

Tags: python, types

I am trying to get a list to write to a text file, the code that adds to the file is this:

```
text_file = open("tim's diner menu.txt", "w")
menu = (["all day breakfast large, £5.50", "all day breafast small, £3.50", "hot dog, £3.00", "burger, £4.00", "cheese burger, £4.25", "chicken goujons, £3.50", "fries, £1.75", "salad, £2.20", "milkshake, £2.20", "soft drinks, £1.30", "still water, £0.90", "sparkling water, £0.90"])
def menu_rewrite():
    for i in menu:
        text_file.write (menu[i])
```

when I run this function, I get the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I ca'n figure pout what is broken and have tried everything i can think of to try and make it work, but it hasnt worked, can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Check the syntax reference. `for` is not use indexes here, this brackets `()` are for tuples...

```
menu = ["all day breakfast large, £5.50", "all day breafast small, £3.50", "hot dog, £3.00", "burger, £4.00", "cheese burger, £4.25", "chicken goujons, £3.50", "fries, £1.75", "salad, £2.20", "milkshake, £2.20", "soft drinks, £1.30", "still water, £0.90", "sparkling water, £0.90"]


def menu_rewrite():
    for item in menu:
        text_file.write(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write `for i in menu`, `i` will take all the values of `menu` one after the other, not their indices, so you need to write `text_file.write(i)` instead of `menu[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `i` is `str`

change to :

```
def menu_rewrite():
    for i in menu:
        text_file.write(i)
```

or

```
def menu_rewrite():
    for i in range(len(menu)):
        text_file.write(menu[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried some of these suggestions and I think they did something, I'm now just getting a different error. thanks for the help to everyone that posted a solution